# Setting AWstats for AWS ELB log format

Tags: linux, awstats

I try Setting AWstats to read AWS ELB log format. The example AWS elb log.

> h2 2023-08-13T23:45:18.034933Z app/AWS-ELB-01/11111111111111 200.1.1.169:43612 172.31.214.153:80 0.001 0.064 0.000 200 200 69 4376184 "GET https://www.test.com.br:443/_sys/css/public/vue/bundle.css?20230810 HTTP/2.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/targetgroup01/46c3d1089efg4ef "Root=1-64d96b05-7bbbbcbe3d67dcaaaaaaaaa" "www.test.com.br" "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789:certificate/274341f3-gggg-fffff-a104-1e22222ef3333" 0 2023-08-13T23:45:09.164000Z "waf,forward" "-" "-" "172.31.214.153:80" "200" "-" "-"

But don't work. I run the awstats.pl

> root@awstats:~# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -showcorrupted -showdropped -config=test -update
> Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.test.conf" by AWStats version 7.6 (build 20161204)
> From data in log file "/tmp/access02.log"...
> Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
> Searching new records from beginning of log file...
> Phase 2 : Now process new records (Flush history on disk after 20000 hosts)...
> Jumped lines in file: 0
> Parsed lines in file: 7
> Found 0 dropped records,
> Found 0 comments,
> Found 0 blank records,
> Found 0 corrupted records,
> Found 0 old records,
> Found 7 new qualified records.
> root@awstats:~#

but in the web interface it does not display anything.

I'm using the follow `LogFormat`.

> LogFormat="%other %time5 %other %host %host_r %request_processing_time %backend_processing_time %response_processing_time %code %backend_status_code %received_bytes %bytesd %methodurl %uaquot %other %other %other %otherquot %refererquot %otherquot %other %time5 %otherquot %otherquot %otherquot %host_r %code %otherquot %otherquot"

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

I need the AWS elb logs to be processed and viewed in the awstats web interface for analysis.